# Is it possible to swap C functions?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Looking to see if anyone knows if its possible to swap C functions...?

```
 void swap2(int(*a)(int), int(*b)(int)) {
   int(*temp)(int) = a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
   // Gives 'Non-object type 'int (int)' is not assignable
 }

 swap2(&funcA, &funcB);
```

**EDIT**

More data here as to intention -- Some answers have been provided below which *do* work such as creating the function ptr using `typedef`, pointing them to the functions and switching those, which lets you invoke the new swapped ptrs successfully.

*BUT* calling the functions by their original names after swapping shows no change. Essentially I'm looking for a c equivalent of the objc "swizzle".

I'm beginning to think this isn't possible, due to c's complete lack of reflection, and would require actually modifying the binary itself (obviously not feasible).  D:

Comments welcome.

Comment: `*b` in `*b=temp` is totally **absurd**.You can dereference a function pointer only to invoke it.

Comment: `*b` is not a valid lvalue to begin with.

Comment: @Thokchom -- While that comment appears to be mostly critical rather than constructive, the point remains that you are correct. That function was an adaptation of a generic pointer swap intended for other data types and obviously incorrect, hence my question here in the first place ** See edit **

Comment: No,no, you are misunderstanding me.Why should I be critical of you?I was only talking about that assignment.I wrote "absurd" in bold to draw your attention to that only.Cheers!!

Comment: @MilesAlden About EDIT part: being able to swap functions at runtime requires runtime decision about which function to call. Some languages may have syntactic sugar about it, but it always boils down to some kind of lookup at what to call (or modification of binary at every place where the function is called, which often is even forbidden by the OS). In C, if you want to have this, you need to do it explicitly, and function pointer is the most straightforward way (but not the only one). IOW, in C, you have to implement reflection features yourself, where you need them.

Answer (score 9):

If you use the function pointers like below, it is yes

```
typedef int (*func_pt)(int);

func_pt a, b;

void swap(func_pt * a, func_pt * b)
{
    func_pt tmp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}

swap(&a, &b);
```

Or you use it as this, I think it is no:

```
int test1(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int test2(int b)
{
    return b;
}

swap(&test1, &test2);
```

Complete compiling working program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (* func_pt)(int);

func_pt a, b;

int test1(int a)
{
    printf("test1\n");
    return 1;
}

int test2(int a)
{
    printf("test2\n");
    return 2;
}

void swap(func_pt * a, func_pt * b)
{
    func_pt tmp = *b;

    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    a = &test1;
    b = &test2;

    printf("before\n");
    a(1);
    b(1);

    swap(&a, &b);

    printf("after\n");
    a(1);
    b(2);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
before
test1
test2
after
test2
test1
```

Some people do not try it by themselves, just say it absurd.So I give you a example.

Comment: This does work as you describe making it possible to swap the typedef'd ptrs, and if you call those they are flipped; however I'm more interested in the 2nd example. I'm essentially looking for the equivalent of swizzling in objective-c for regular c functions. Here we're invoking these pointers, but if I call test1(1), it still calls test1() instead of test2(). Any ideas there?

Comment: @MilesAlden: Function names are "address constants".  Standard C won't let you change them, and is allowed to set your computer on fire if you if you somehow managed to.  If you want to switch out implementations at will, you'd have to have function pointers representing each of them, and always call the functions through those pointers.  That effectively kills many forms of optimization, though.

Comment: "...allowed to set your computer on fire..." Just literally laughed out loud at that one, thanks. :-) Ya that's what I was gleaning here.

Comment: @cHao As fun as it is to say how UB allows compiler to set your compiler on fire, it's so inaccurate it's getting old. Actually it just doesn't forbid compiler from doing so, but C standard does not have the authority to *allow* that even if it wanted. Standard is not the only thing compiler has to adhere to. Additionally, the standard does not *forbid* standard code from producing too much heat and setting your computer on fire, simply because compiler does not have a way to control heat production.

Comment: @hyde: You forgot the <pedantry> tags.  :P  The point is, C itself places no limits on the resulting behavior.  Your computer maker and the CPSC are what keep the fire from happening.

Comment: @cHao Yeah, sure. It just seems to be a bit too common to write some fictional hyperbole about what happens if you invoke UB, and that's what triggered my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you need pointers to function pointers to swap pointers, no? This type of swapping function swaps values; you really want to deal in addresses. The example function call wouldn't really work because C doesn't treat functions as first-class variables so you can't actually swap functions directly; you need to use pointers to function addresses, since addresses CAN be swapped:

```
void swap2(int(**a)(int), int(**b)(int)) {
   int(*temp)(int) = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = *temp;
}

int(*func1)(int) = &foo;
int(*func2)(int) = &bar;

swap2(&func1, &func2);
```

Comment: Well this works in the scope of the function but doesn't alter the actual function pointer addresses. Print the function pointers before and after and you'll see.

Comment: Like you could call func1() & func2(), which are now swapped, but calling foo() & bar() show them unaffected.

Comment: Function addresses are constant; you can't move code in C without a LOT more effort, under the right conditions, such as the code segment actually being writable, or doing a lot of assembly-level wizardry, and if the stars are aligned you won't crash your computer :D.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will give error like "invalid lvalue" at the time of assignment. As I can see in your code you are trying to swap pointers without changing its values so have a look on below solution.

```
void swap2(int(**a)(int), int(**b)(int)) {   
   int(*temp)(int) = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
}

int main(){
    int(*temp1)(int) = &funcA;
    int(*temp2)(int) = &funcB;
    swap2(&temp1,&temp2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can. Think that a function-pointer is just a memory-address,the single requeriment is: where you will keep such address needs to be mutable. Say,`int (*foo)()` not really to where `foo` points to. May be to `printf()` or `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the subject asks about swapping functions, you actually want to emulate what `swizzle` does. This just means you want to be able to call the same function name but have it do something different.

A pointer only solution will not give you that behavior. If that is not important to you, then you should adopt one of the function pointer only solutions provided. If it *is* important to you, then, you will need to introduce a layer of abstraction. The abstraction could use function pointers under the hood (although there are other solutions).

The API to users of this interface would be:

```
/* API to initialize */
void abstract_func_init ();

/* API to manipulate abstract functions */
typedef int abstract_func_type ();
abstract_func_type * abstract_func_get (abstract_func_type *key);
int abstract_func_set (abstract_func_type *key, abstract_func_type *behavior);

/* the abstract functions */
extern int foo ();
extern int bar ();
```

The implementation of such an interface could look like:

```
static void insert (abstract_func_type *key, abstract_func_type **behavior)
{ /* associate key to behavior */ }
static abstract_func_type ** lookup (abstract_func_type *key)
{ /* return behavior from key */ }

abstract_func_type * abstract_func_get (abstract_func_type *k) {
    abstract_func_type **f = lookup(k);
    if (f) return *f;
    return 0;
}

int abstract_func_set (abstract_func_type *k, abstract_func_type *p) {
    abstract_func_type **f = lookup(k);
    if (f) {
        *f = p;
        return 0;
    }
    return -ENOENT;
}

#define DEFINE_ABSTRACT_FUNC(func) \
    static int static_##func (); \
    static abstract_func_type *func##_ptr = static_##func; \
    int func () { return func##_ptr(); } \
    static int static_##func ()

DEFINE_ABSTRACT_FUNC(foo) { return puts("foo"); }
DEFINE_ABSTRACT_FUNC(bar) { return puts("bar"); }

void abstract_func_init () {
    insert(foo, &foo_ptr);
    insert(bar, &bar_ptr);
}
```

Then, the `swap()` you initially presented in your post could be implemented like this:

```
void swap (abstract_func_type *a, abstract_func_type *b) {
    abstract_func_type *ap = abstract_func_get(a);
    abstract_func_type *bp = abstract_func_get(b);
    abstract_func_set(a, bp);
    abstract_func_set(b, ap);
}
```

Here is a program that calls `swap()`:

```
    puts("before swap");
    foo();
    bar();
    swap(foo, bar);
    puts("after swap");
    foo();
    bar();
```

And its output would be:

```
before swap
foo
bar
after swap
bar
foo
```

To automate the adding of abstract functions into the lookup table, you could introduce into the build system an extra step that called a script that would `grep` out the `DEFINE_ABSTRACT_FUNC` lines, and generate a new source file that had a function with the calls to `insert()` for each such line.

A complete version of the mock-up can be found [here](http://ideone.com/WxG8CQ).

Comment: Yay, another non-constructive downvote. As a pre-emptive response, this solution uses an abstraction layer between the API and the delegated action of the API. The `swizzle()` API is used to swap the delegated actions. It gives the behavior that the poster asked for (calling the same APIs by name now produces different behavior).

Comment: Problem is, it's useless.  It requires altering one (or both!) of the endpoints of the call.  That defeats every sane reason for wanting to swap names rather than use a function pointer explicitly.

Comment: @cHao: Since no such feature exists in C++, but the behavior is desired, then the only way to provide the behavior is to introduce an abstraction in code. You can do things like introduce macros to make defining a "swizzle-able" function easier, but how can you introduce a new behavior without writing new code?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've introduced a desired behavior, though.  You've certainly built a cute look-alike, but (1) it's unusable in nearly every case where the desired behavior would actually seem desirable; (2) it's not providing functionality (or even abstraction!) over what a function pointer provides; and (3) it's more work to implement.  Where's the benefit to doing it like this, rather than simply pretending a function pointer is a function?

Comment: @cHao: I take it that the asker wants to be able to declare a function normally, like `extern int foo();` rather than `extern int (*foo)();`, and so with that in mind, an abstraction is required, i.e., `foo()` calls through a swappable function pointer. It is more work for the implementer of the "swizzle" API, yes. The benefit is for the user of the "swizzle" API.

Comment: Actually this is pretty darned useful, and thanks for writing it. Essentially you've pieced together a chunk of the objc runtime, which uses a similar lookup action which then enables swizzling.

Comment: The thing about swizzling that makes it worth doing at all, is that the code being swapped out usually doesn't even *know*.  You can add functionality where the old code didn't provide any hooks to do so.  Once you start having to have functions set themselves up to be swapped out, 99% of the usefulness is gone -- and you're left with little but functions whose names you can't even trust anymore.

Comment: @cHao: That seems to be a pretty narrow view of what `swizzle()` is used for. To me, this is just another incarnation of the State pattern.

Comment: To the down-voters, the primary objection seems to be that the solution is overly complex to the task. However, the asker posed a specific requirement, and no other solution has addressed that requirement. If you prefer "that's a silly requirement, do it this way instead" answers over a serious attempt to actually address the requirement, then down-vote away.

Comment: There's not an object in sight here.  OO patterns don't apply.  But either way, if you want to call swapping functions an incarnation of State, it's the most broken incarnation i've ever seen.  Besides the fact that it has client code mucking around with implementation details, what happens when there are 2 dozen of these functions?  How do you even *find* your old self again?

Comment: @cHao: If there are lots of swizzleable functions, then the user of the interface has many to choose from. You are asking me for a use case, but I am not the one that presented the requirement. But, off the top of my head, one could use `swizzle()` to explicitly swap out a single threaded version of the API for an MT-safe version of the same API.

Comment: @cHao: You can just maintain a copy of the original mappings to be able restore the old self. Since I don't code in objective-C, the complete spec would have to be presented to me for me to present a complete solution, but such a question would be not welcome on StackOverflow anyway. So different requirements should be presented as different questions.

Comment: So now when someone calls in to the MT-safe functions, they get the ST ones instead.  Nice.  You're helping illustrate my point here; the cases where one would want to *swap* functions, outside of replacing functionality from outside (and needing access to the old functionality), are few and far between.  Far more likely (and useful) is *setting* a pointer to the desired function.

Comment: @cHao: Again, I would need to have a complete set of requirements to present a complete solution. I imagine that there could be a special value to swizzle against to disable an API (e.g. like `SIG_IGN` for signal handlers).

Comment: @cHao: Anyway, you just seem to be complaining that the solution doesn't have a rich enough set of APIs. I am sure the asker can extend the solution to account for whatever other requirements are needed. The objection seems kind of petty at this point. I'll just take the downvote. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: My objection is that this method is fundamentally broken in a dozen ways, *and* doesn't do anything worth doing.  A decent API might be able to *partially* fix some issues, but not all.  And there isn't one here anyway.

Comment: @cHao: This is just proof that your objections are petty. You never were never close to presenting how this is broken in a dozen ways. And, it's just a lie, since my solution uses a function pointer as the underlying mechanism. My solution has all the same benefits of a "function pointer only" solution by adding two APIs to get and set the underlying pointer. But, on top of that, my solution actually satisfies the asker's requirement, which a pointer only solution does not. You don't like the solution fine, but it's just shameful to make up lies as to why it's bad. Good grief.

Comment: I've presented at least 7 reasons so far.  I'm sure i could come up with 5 more.

Comment: @cHao: I already explained how your objections are merely noise, and why any other objections you would have would also be noise. In any case, I updated the answer to address the only substantial objection you had.

Comment: @user315052: *Saying* something over and over isn't *explaining* it.  But anyway. If i put aside the brokenness of the idea for a second, dismiss altogether the idea of swapping arbitrary functions, and just call these "function pointer wrapper functions", the implementation doesn't look as bad as it started out. I'll probably never agree that it's useful or desirable to do this, but it at least approaches usability if you have a set of predetermined functions (all with the same arg and return types) to switch between. Removing my downvote, as there's (a real part of) an actual solution now.

Comment: @cHao: If there is already object code that cannot be changed, this idea can still be used to allow that object code to link against the same function name, but allow that object code to benefit from a dynamically alterable behavior. A function pointer only solution just cannot offer that.

Comment: @user315052: If that function is intended to be defined in the calling code, you have a point.  (Though that's a horrible design, IMO.)  But it seems like it'd get tricky trying to switch out an existing function in *other* object code you can't change.  That's basically the point (and the power) of method swizzling in Objective-C: you add a method `doThisInstead:`, swizzle `doThis:` and `doThisInstead:`, and now `doThis:` messages to instances automagically get redirected to `doThisInstead:`'s method and vice versa.  Often without the class or the caller even knowing.

Comment: @cHao: I don't understand why you keep trying to say this is a horrible design. You speak as though the design should drive the requirement, but it is always the other way around. If you are required to introduce the dynamic function behavior as described in this question to a closed source third party library that comes pre-compiled, what design choice would you make differently?

Comment: @user315052: The horrible design i'm talking about in this case is that of a third-party library that expects a function with a hard-coded name rather than having you provide a pointer to a callback.  If you have to work around that, then these FPWFs might be the least evil workaround.  But make no mistake: this *is* design driving requirements.  It's just not as much *your* design that's driving them at that point, but that of the library you are using.

Comment: @cHao: The third-party library had no intention of providing any dynamic behavior. It is "you" that has evolved such a requirement.

Comment: @user315052: Regardless of what it intended, it's rather bad form to say "call your function `whatever`", when it takes about 5 lines of code to provide the ability to set a callback (one for the variable, one to set it, and two for the function declaration and braces -- plus maybe one for returning the old function pointer so it can be restored later).

Comment: @cHao: It is more like your requirements changed to make you need to dynamically alter a POSIX function, because you need a level of dynamism that the library never intended to provide.

Comment: @user315052: If you need to dynamically alter a standard function in order to *trick* a library into doing what you want, (a) the library isn't as useful as you think it is, and (b) your design is too clever for its own good.  Any code that does stuff like that should be rejected on the grounds that it flies in the face of POLS.

Comment: @cHao: Again, you think that the design can drive the requirements (meaning that you think the design of the software can be used to convince the customer to change their mind about what they need). You are a developer given a job. I guess you would refuse to do the job. That's fine, more money for me.

Comment: @user315052: A requirement that you use Library X to do a job it was never intended to do, *is itself driven by design*.  With that aside, though, it's also fundamentally unsound. As engineers, we have a *duty* to point that out and come up with better alternatives. The people that expect you to shut up and use Library X anyway? They just want a code monkey.  You can take all of those if you want, though they almost invariably want to *pay* you like a code monkey as well.  The stress/cash ratio is way too high, IMO, to justify working with them unless you *really* need the money.

Comment: @cHao: A requirement is a requirement. A solution satisfies the requirement. You want to present an argument to justify why the requirement is bad, and claim it is a solution. But, in reality, you just don't want to solve the presented problem for personal reasons. Very seldom is there an intellectual argument that is convincing enough to get a customer to agree to those terms. You are allowed to present trade-offs between different solutions, but it is rare that anyone would pick one that doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: @user315052: Let's say i require a three-story house made entirely of Jell-O.  I had some plans drawn and everything, somehow -- it'd be spectacular.  A home builder that has any integrity at all, though, will tell me (politely, of course) how bad an idea that is.  He will suggest materials easier to build with, less likely to fall apart/melt/attract critters/wobble away in an earthquake/etc etc etc, but that still kinda *look* and *feel* like Jell-O.  But if i insist that it *must* be made entirely of Jell-O, they will almost certainly refuse the job.

Comment: @cHao: Yeah, I can see how that analogy is entirely irrelevant, except for the part about refusing to do the job. I agree you are always free to do that.

Comment: @user315052: I think the analogy is particularly relevant, considering your entire argument to this point revolves around a requirement to build something using materials that obviously aren't meant for the job, and how it's just plain petty to object to such a requirement.  Point is, a requirement is not always a *valid* requirement...and a responsible engineer will point out and refuse invalid requirements.

Comment: @cHao: It is irrelevant, because you should always consider the safety of the customer. However, unless the software is being used in a mission critical realtime application, a software design decision is almost never a life and death decision. And for this particular problem and my particular solution, it has equivalent properties to a plain pointer on top of the advantage of satisfying the requirement. Your Jell-O example is thus not an appropriate analogue. But, if the purpose of the house is to eat it, then the builder that refused lost out on some major dough.

Comment: @user315052: The "safety of the customer", when it comes to building software, is the stability of the system we build for them.  The system which, in many cases, could kill their business or subject them (and us!) to huge lawsuits if something goes wrong with it.  A "requirement" by the customer does not make it OK to turn your code into a minefield.

Comment: @cHao: And you are free to refuse the job if you feel it puts you and the customer at risk. Just as I am free to take the job if I feel the risk is manageable.